# How to implement LSD in opencv 4.1.0

Tags: python, opencv

I had implemented LSD in my open CV project. Every thing worked well until I upgraded opencv version from 4.0.0 to 4.1.0. Now I get error as

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/lsd.cpp:143: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Implementation has been removed due original code license issues in function 'LineSegmentDetectorImpl'
```

It seems that due to some liscense issue this feature has been removed. How do I address this problem.

The error is shown in the following part of code :

```
cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0)
```

Comment: looks like is is still available https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d73/classcv_1_1LineSegmentDetector.html maybe different syntax/usage now?

Comment: As Line Segment Detector has been removed due to license conflict, I suggest you all add a thumbs-up to this issue!   
"Restore LineSegmentDetector LSD & avoid license conflict": https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2524#issue-615242133

Answer (score 4):

In opencv 4, it is now called FastLineDetector. You need to first install opencv-contrib-python by using `pip install opencv-contrib-python` and then you can use the following implementation

```
img = cv2.imread(test_image, 0)
fld = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector()
lines = fld.detect(img)
result_img = fld.drawSegments(img,lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

there is an older implementation of [line segment detector with bindings for python, matlab here](https://github.com/primetang/LSD-OpenCV-MATLAB/tree/master/pylsd)

`$ pip install pylsd`

worked for me