# Error with obtaining license OpenCV project

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to make a machine learning model with Python. However, I keep getting this error:

```
LSD = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(_refine=cv2.LSD_REFINE_ADV, _quant=qError)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/lsd.cpp:143: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Implementation has been removed due original code license issues in function 'LineSegmentDetectorImpl'
```

My code is as follows:

```
_, vp, _, _, panoEdge, _, _ = panoEdgeDetection(img_ori,
                                                    qError=args.q_error,
                                                    refineIter=args.refine_iter)
    panoEdge = (panoEdge > 0)
```

How can I fix this? Thanks to all. Satya

Comment: do see my answer let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be happening due to the function `LineSegmentDetectorImpl` being deprecated in latest version. For example, if you are using this opencv-contrib-`python==4.1.1.26` and opencv-`python==4.1.1.26`.

To solve it:

Downgrade to opencv-contrib-`python==4.0.0.21` and `opencv-python==4.0.0.21.`

According to this question on [Stakoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016650/how-to-implement-lsd-in-opencv-4-1-0), to replace the missing LineSegmentDetectorImpl, install pylsd using pip install pylsd. For more details about how to use it with opencv, please check the [documentation](https://github.com/primetang/LSD-OpenCV-MATLAB/tree/master/pylsd).

This should solve the problem.